# Oracle APEX: Interactive grid PL/SQL Process

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to add an Interactive Grid with columns from Master-Details Tables.
So I create a query with a join between master and details, and create a control break to categorize it (Control Break on Master table ID).
I changed the save process Target Type to PL/SQL Code, and I wrote a code that works fine.

`declare

cg$rec_its  cg$scm_inventory_trans.cg$row_type;
cg$ind_its  cg$scm_inventory_trans.cg$ind_type; 
cg$rec_itl  cg$scm_inventory_trans_dtls.cg$row_type;
cg$ind_itl  cg$scm_inventory_trans_dtls.cg$ind_type;
l_its_id    scm_inventory_trans.id%type;
begin
case :APEX$ROW_STATUS
    when 'C' then
   cg$rec_its.ite_id              := 63;
   cg$ind_its.ite_id              := true; 
   cg$rec_its.whs_id              := :WHS_ID;
   cg$ind_its.whs_id              := true;

   cg$rec_its.whs_id_transfer_in  := :WHS_ID_TRANSFER_IN;
   cg$ind_its.whs_id_transfer_in  := true; 
   cg$rec_its.trans_date          := sysdate;
   cg$ind_its.trans_date          := true;
   cg$scm_inventory_trans.ins(cg$rec_its,cg$ind_its,true);
   l_its_id := cg$rec_its.id;
   cg$rec_itl.its_id              := l_its_id;
   cg$ind_itl.its_id              := true;
   cg$rec_itl.whs_id              := :WHS_ID;
   cg$ind_itl.whs_id              := true;

   cg$rec_itl.itm_id              := :ITM_ID;
   cg$ind_itl.itm_id              := true;
   cg$rec_itl.mut_id              := :MUT_ID;
   cg$ind_itl.mut_id              := true;
   cg$rec_itl.its_id              := l_its_id;
   cg$ind_itl.its_id              := true;

   cg$rec_itl.qty                 := :QTY;
   cg$ind_itl.qty                 := true;
   cg$scm_inventory_trans_dtls.ins(cg$rec_itl,cg$ind_itl,true);
    when 'U' then
   cg$rec_its.ite_id              := 63;
   cg$ind_its.ite_id              := true; 
   cg$rec_its.whs_id              := :WHS_ID;
   cg$ind_its.whs_id              := true;

   cg$rec_its.whs_id_transfer_in  := :WHS_ID_TRANSFER_IN;
   cg$ind_its.whs_id_transfer_in  := true; 
   cg$rec_its.trans_date          := sysdate;
   cg$ind_its.trans_date          := true;
   cg$scm_inventory_trans.upd(cg$rec_its,cg$ind_its,true);
   cg$rec_itl.its_id              := l_its_id;
   cg$ind_itl.its_id              := true; 
   cg$rec_itl.whs_id              := :WHS_ID;
   cg$ind_itl.whs_id              := true;

   cg$rec_itl.itm_id              := :ITM_ID;
   cg$ind_itl.itm_id              := true;
   cg$rec_itl.mut_id              := :MUT_ID;
   cg$ind_itl.mut_id              := true;
   cg$rec_itl.its_id              := l_its_id;
   cg$ind_itl.its_id              := true;

   cg$rec_itl.qty                 := :QTY;
   cg$ind_itl.qty                 := true; 
   cg$scm_inventory_trans_dtls.upd(cg$rec_itl,cg$ind_itl,true);
    when 'D' then
        delete scm_inventory_trans
         where rowid = :ROWID;
    end case;
end;`
The issue that I CANNOT edit the fields in IG I tried to change IG attributes with no results, the fields just go gray and not clickable, any help please?
Regards

Comment: Is the editable attribute for your interactive grid enable?

Comment: Yes it is, and that's what drives me crazy

Comment: All editable columns are text fields, select lists, etc. And all columns have the attribute "query only" setting to no? If the type is correct and the attribute "query only" is setting to no, so, I don't know what's happening with your IG.